# Moving from reflection to expression-tree

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I have a reflection code, to create an instance of `List<>` (type parameter known at run-time), and call `Add` method to add some values to it. My snippet is something like this:

```
// here is my type parameter
var genericType = typeof(MyRunTimeType);
// here is a list of my values
MyRunTimeType[] values = MyRunTimeValuesOfTypeMyRunTimeType();

// creating instance of List<>
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var listGenericType = listType.MakeGenericType(genericType);
var listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listGenericType);

// getting Add method and call it
var addMethod = listGenericType.GetMethod("Add", genericType);
foreach (var value invalues)
    addMethod.Invoke(listInstance, new[] { value });
```

So, how would you suggest to convert this reflection snippet to an expression-tree?

**UPDATE:**

Well, I wrote this snippet, which seems closed to work:

```
public static Func<IEnumerable<object>, object> GetAndFillListMethod(Type genericType) {

    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var listGenericType = listType.MakeGenericType(genericType);

    var values = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericType), "values");

    var ctor = listGenericType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[0], null);
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(listGenericType, "list");

    var assign = Expression.Assign(instance, Expression.New(ctor));

    var addMethod = listGenericType.GetMethod("AddRange", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericType) });

    var addCall = Expression.Call(instance, addMethod, new Expression[] { values });

    var block = Expression.Block(
          new[] { instance },
          assign,
          addCall,
          Expression.Convert(instance, typeof(object))
        );

    return (Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>)Expression.Lambda(block, values).Compile();
}
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 
'System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String],System.Object]' 
to type 
'System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object],System.Object]'.
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Why not just call `ToList()` on `MyRunTimeValuesOfTypeMyRunTimeType()`? It's an array, right?

Comment: This isn't a question but you want someone to do your work... You should start doing it yourself and if you find some blocking issue in your code, you can come here again and ask specific questions.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer the blocking point is: how should I start?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry This isn't enough to ask a question in SO... Start reading MSDN articles about how to work with expression trees, do your own testing, ...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer See the update please

Comment: @Javad_Amiry BTW, what's the purpose of using expression trees if you compile them to return a delegate?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry Your problem is in the fact that you are trying to return a `Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>` but your func is in truth a `Func<IEnumerable<T>, object>`.

Comment: @xanatos Am I mistaken if I think that this case doesn't need expression trees but it can be solved using a delegate of type `Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>` auto-inferred from an anonymous delegate which matches the whole delegate signature? ;P

Comment: cant you use dynamic?

Comment: @MBoros No, performance issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working:

```
public static Func<IEnumerable<object>, object> GetAndFillListMethod(Type genericType)
{
    var listType = typeof(List<>);
    var listGenericType = listType.MakeGenericType(genericType);

    var values = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<object>), "values");

    var ctor = listGenericType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[0], null);

    // I prefer using Expression.Variable to Expression.Parameter
    // for internal variables
    var instance = Expression.Variable(listGenericType, "list");

    var assign = Expression.Assign(instance, Expression.New(ctor));

    var addMethod = listGenericType.GetMethod("AddRange", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericType) });

    // Enumerable.Cast<T>
    var castMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) }).MakeGenericMethod(genericType);

    // For the parameters there is a params Expression[], so no explicit array necessary
    var castCall = Expression.Call(castMethod, values);
    var addCall = Expression.Call(instance, addMethod, castCall);

    var block = Expression.Block(
            new[] { instance },
            assign,
            addCall,
            Expression.Convert(instance, typeof(object))
        );

    return (Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>)Expression.Lambda(block, values).Compile();
}
```

Your problem is in the fact that you are trying to return a `Func<IEnumerable<object>, object>` but your func is in truth a `Func<IEnumerable<T>, object>`. The solution is to make the parameter a `IEnumerable<object>` and then use `Enumerable.Cast<T>` before passing to `AddRange`

I've changed the `Expression.Parameter` used for `instance` to a `Expression.Variable`... But it is only to make it more clear that it is a variable, not a parameter. The expression tree generated by `Expression.Variable` and by `Expression.Parameter` is the same (because the two functions have the same code). It is the context where it is used that defines if it is a parameter or a variable. I've done another small change: `Expression.Call` doesn't need an explicit array initialization for the parameters.

Ah... And note that the last line of the `Block` could be:

```
addCall,
instance
```

instead of being

```
addCall,    
Expression.Convert(instance, typeof(object))
```

because any reference type is implicitly convertible to `object`.

Comment: It works like a charm :) I forgot about `castMethod`. thanks ;)